# Redux-persist react native AsyncStorage Object Serialization Objects Not Equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using redux persist to automatically persist and rehydrate the state on application launch as described in the docs, specifically using AsyncStorage: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist.

I have a reducer defined below which keeps the current products added to the shopping cart in state.products

```
case 'ADD_PRODUCT':
  let addedProducts = [...state.products]
  addedProducts.push(action.product);
  return {
    ...state,
    count: ++state.count,
    products: addedProducts
  };

case 'REMOVE_PRODUCT':
  let count = state.count;
  let removedProducts = [...state.products];
  let idxOfProduct = state.products.indexOf(action.product);
  if(idxOfProduct != -1){
    count = --state.count;
    removedProducts.splice(idxOfProduct,1);
  }

return{
    ...state,
    count: count,
    products: removedProducts
    };
```

#1. If I dispatch 'ADD_PRODUCT', it adds the product and then if I dispatch 'REMOVE_PRODUCT' it removes the item as expected.

#2.1 If I dispatch ADD_PRODUCT and then RELOAD my app, the state.products is rehydrated as expected and contains the recently added product.

#2.1.However attempt to call REMOVE_PRODUCT (exactly the same way I called REMOVE_PRODUCT in #1 above) after a I have RELOAD the app. Even though state.products contains the product `state.products.indexOf(action.product);` returns back -1 and as a result it is not removed.

Why does IndexOf method in #1 work correct as expected when REMOVE_PRODUCT is called. However if I add a product(ADD_PRODUCT) then reload my app and call REMOVE_PRODUCT, IndexOf returns -1 even though it is present in the state.products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because indexOf uses a [strict reference equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) check to find the element within the array. This means that it's not enough for the objects to have the same fields and values: it needs to be the very same object. After the app has been reloaded, this can never be true, since the original object has been destroyed.

If your products have some sort of unique ID field, the easiest way to do this would be to filter the list to exclude the item with a matching id:

```
const products = state.products.filter(p => p.id !== action.product.id);
const count = products.length;

return { ...state, products, count };
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be related to the way indexOf treats object equality.

Without reloading, you are adding and removing the same object reference, which is OK.

When you reload, the reference loaded in `state.products` is different from the one in `action.product`, so indexOf cannot find it and never returns the index.

To fix this I would use the product id to find that product in the `state.products` array instead of trying to find the whole object.

To illustrate a bit my answer, this is what you are doing:

```
var a = {obj: 0};
var b = [a];
b.indexOf({obj: 0}); // -1 not found
```

This is what you should do:

```
var a = {id: '26833', obj: 0};
var b = [a];
b.findIndex(function(el){ //findIndex is not supported in IE, find a polyfill for it
   return el.id === '26833'
}); //0
```